# How do you return clusters in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm very new for neo4j.

Need to get output as array for already grouped nodes.[image]

In attached image having 13 node groups.

For example,

['img8','img9','img47','img50','img51'] is one set

['img20', 'img21'] is another set.

Like this we are having 13 node sets in attached image.

I need output like.

[[set1],[set2],.....,[set13]]

Comment: maybe through https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.2/overview/apoc.path/apoc.path.subgraphAll/ . do you perhaps have the insertion code to test a bit?

Comment: Use COLLECT to get an aggregated list of those sets. But first you need to filter out isolated nodes (those nodes without a connection). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you [install](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/installation/) the Neo4j Graph Data Science (GDS) plugin, you can use community detection algorithms. In particular, the [Weakly Connected Components](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/wcc/) (WCC) algorithm will be useful for you use case. Here is a snippet from its documentation:

> The Weakly Connected Components (WCC) algorithm finds sets of
> connected nodes in directed and undirected graphs. Two nodes are
> connected, if there exists a path between them. The set of all nodes
> that are connected with each other form a component. In contrast to
> Strongly Connected Components (SCC), the direction of relationships on
> the path between two nodes is not considered.

For example, if you only care about `Img` nodes (with `name` properties) and `DISTANCE` relationships, you can do something like this:

```
// Create an in-memory GDS projection for the Img nodes and DISTANCE relationships
CALL gds.graph.project('imgs', 'Img', 'DISTANCE') YIELD graphName
// Run WCC algorithm to find each "component", in which every pair of nodes is connected by some path (ignoring directionality)
CALL gds.wcc.stream('imgs', {}) YIELD nodeId, componentId
// For each component, collect a list of the names of all nodes in that component
WITH componentId, COLLECT(gds.util.asNode(nodeId).name) AS names
// Collect all those lists into an outer list (this is the result you asked for)
RETURN COLLECT(names) AS result
```

The GDS projection will keep taking up memory on the server until your drop the projection or restart neo4j. To drop the projection named "imgs", do this:

```
CALL gds.graph.drop('imgs')
```

The above is barely scratching the surface of GDS, but should give you a leg up on implementing your use case.

Comment: I am wondering if there is a way to do this, with cypher only, that is if there is a graph pattern matching solution to this. Any idea about that ?